# Access IP camera with OpenCV

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, ip-camera

Can't access the video stream. Can any one please help me to get the video stream. I have searched in google for the solution and post another question in stack overflow but unfortunately nothing can't solve the problem.

```
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture()
cap.open('http://192.168.4.133:80/videostream.cgi?user=admin&pwd=admin')
while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: What happens instead?

Comment: Maybe this will help anyone finding this thread?  How to use opencv to capture video and using threads so much higher frame rate and reduced delay https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55828451/video-streaming-from-ip-camera-in-python-using-opencv-cv2-videocapture

Answer (score 5):

Use code below to access ipcam directly through opencv. Replace the url in VideoCapture with your particular camera rtsp url. The one given generally works for most cameras I've used.

```
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture("rtsp://[username]:[pass]@[ip address]/media/video1")

while True:
    ret, image = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow("Test", image)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use urllib to read frames from video stream.

```
import cv2
import urllib
import numpy as np

stream = urllib.urlopen('http://192.168.100.128:5000/video_feed')
bytes = ''
while True:
    bytes += stream.read(1024)
    a = bytes.find(b'\xff\xd8')
    b = bytes.find(b'\xff\xd9')
    if a != -1 and b != -1:
        jpg = bytes[a:b+2]
        bytes = bytes[b+2:]
        img = cv2.imdecode(np.fromstring(jpg, dtype=np.uint8), cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
        cv2.imshow('Video', img)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) == 27:
            exit(0)
```

Check this out if you want to stream video from webcam of your pc. https://github.com/shehzi-khan/video-streaming

Comment: `urllib` and `urllib2` are not available on Python 3.x

Answer (score 3):

You can use this code to get live video feeds in browser.

for accessing camera other than your laptop's webcam, you can use RTSP link like this

> rtsp://admin:12345@192.168.1.1:554/h264/ch1/main/av_stream"

where

> ```
>    username:admin
>    password:12345
>    your camera ip address and port
>    ch1 is first camera on that DVR
> ```
>
> replace cv2.VideoCamera(0) with this link like this for your camera
>   and it will work

**camera.py**

```
import cv2

class VideoCamera(object):
    def __init__(self):
        # Using OpenCV to capture from device 0. If you have trouble capturing
        # from a webcam, comment the line below out and use a video file
        # instead.
        self.video = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        # If you decide to use video.mp4, you must have this file in the folder
        # as the main.py.
        # self.video = cv2.VideoCapture('video.mp4')

    def __del__(self):
        self.video.release()

    def get_frame(self):
        success, image = self.video.read()
        # We are using Motion JPEG, but OpenCV defaults to capture raw images,
        # so we must encode it into JPEG in order to correctly display the
        # video stream.
        ret, jpeg = cv2.imencode('.jpg', image)
        return jpeg.tobytes()
```

**main.py**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, Response
from camera import VideoCamera

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

def gen(camera):
    while True:
        frame = camera.get_frame()
        yield (b'--frame\r\n'
               b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n\r\n')

@app.route('/video_feed')
def video_feed():
    return Response(gen(VideoCamera()),
                    mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True)
```

then you can follow [this blog](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/12/21/increasing-webcam-fps-with-python-and-opencv/) to increase your FPS of video stream

Answer (score 2):

Thank You. May be, now  urlopen is not under utllib. It is under urllib.request.urlopen.I use this code:

```
import cv2
from urllib.request import urlopen
import numpy as np

stream = urlopen('http://192.168.4.133:80/video_feed')
bytes = ''
while True:
    bytes += stream.read(1024)
    a = bytes.find(b'\xff\xd8')
    b = bytes.find(b'\xff\xd9')
    if a != -1 and b != -1:
        jpg = bytes[a:b+2]
        bytes = bytes[b+2:]
        img = cv2.imdecode(np.fromstring(jpg, dtype=np.uint8), cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
        cv2.imshow('Video', img)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) == 27:
            exit(0)
```

Comment: This does not work on python 3 `TypeError: Can't convert 'bytes' object to str implicitly`

Comment: `urllib` and `urllib2` are not available on Python 3.x

Answer (score 2):

You can Use RTSP instead of direct video feed.

Every IP Camera have RTSP to Stream Live Video.

So you can use RTSP Link instead of videofeed

Answer (score 2):

If using python 3, you will probably need to use a bytearray instead of a string. (modifying the current top answer)

```
with urllib.request.urlopen('http://192.168.100.128:5000/video_feed') as stream:

    bytes = bytearray()

    while True:
        bytes += stream.read(1024)
        a = bytes.find(b'\xff\xd8')
        b = bytes.find(b'\xff\xd9')
        if a != -1 and b != -1:
            jpg = bytes[a:b+2]
            bytes = bytes[b+2:]
            img = cv2.imdecode(np.frombuffer(jpg, dtype=np.uint8), cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
            cv2.imshow('Video', img)
            if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```