# How to read IP camera using OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, ip-camera

Im experiencing issues reading in IP camera stream. It seems I can only access the video stream using Internet Explorer due to ActiveX plugin dependency. It is available on 192.168.0.8:8000. See image below
[image: ipcam]

Once logged in, Im redirected to a htm page that display all camera channels

I have ran zenmap scan on the IP, see image below

[image: Zenmap scan]

How can i get/access camera IP url with just the stream ending in .mpeg, .mjpeg or  .cgi so I can use python CV2 library to read stream for each camera?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check it:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49978705/access-ip-camera-in-python-opencv

Comment: @ Alex Piskunov, thatnks for your response, that question does  not answer how to access multipe camera on same rstp?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you haven't found the solution yet. So I'll try show a possible solution.

When trying to connect OpenCV to IP camera you will need two thing: 1. the IP address of camera, 2. the type of service(protocol) you will use.

In your image you have the IP 192.168.0.8 and the two service RSTP and HTTP in this case you could use this URL:

`rtsp://yourCamLogin:yourCamPassword@192.168.0.8:554/yourCamStreamService`,

after you have found the correct ***yourCamLogin***, ***yourCamPassword*** and ***yourCamStreamService*** you can check the streaming using VLC stream from network.
Lastly, you can use the OpenCV like this:

`cap = cv2.VideoCapture("rtsp://admin:admin@192.168.0.8:554/11")`

Good luck!