# How to detect/recognize face using IP Cam instead of USB Web Cam

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, face-recognition, dlib

I am learning and working on a face recognition college project.

**face-recogition.py**

```
from imutils.video import VideoStream
import face_recognition
import argparse
import imutils
import pickle
import time
import cv2

ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-e", "--encodings", required=True,
    help="path to serialized db of facial encodings")
ap.add_argument("-o", "--output", type=str,
    help="path to output video")
ap.add_argument("-y", "--display", type=int, default=1,
    help="whether or not to display output frame to screen")
ap.add_argument("-d", "--detection-method", type=str, default="cnn",
    help="face detection model to use: either `hog` or `cnn`")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())

print("[INFO] loading encodings...")
data = pickle.loads(open(args["encodings"], "rb").read())

print("[INFO] starting video stream...")
vs = VideoStream(src=0).start()
writer = None
time.sleep(2.0)

while True:
    frame = vs.read()

    rgb = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    rgb = imutils.resize(frame, width=260)
    r = frame.shape[0] / float(rgb.shape[0])

    boxes = face_recognition.face_locations(rgb,
        model=args["detection_method"])
    encodings = face_recognition.face_encodings(rgb, boxes)
    names = []

    for encoding in encodings:

        matches = face_recognition.compare_faces(data["encodings"],
            encoding)
        name = "Unknown"

        if True in matches:

            matchedIdxs = [i for (i, b) in enumerate(matches) if b]
            counts = {}

            for i in matchedIdxs:
                name = data["names"][i]
                counts[name] = counts.get(name, 0) + 1

            name = max(counts, key=counts.get)

        names.append(name)

    for ((top, right, bottom, left), name) in zip(boxes, names):

        top = int(top * r)
        right = int(right * r)
        bottom = int(bottom * r)
        left = int(left * r)

        cv2.rectangle(frame, (left, top), (right, bottom),
            (0, 255, 0), 2)
        y = top - 15 if top - 15 > 15 else top + 15
        cv2.putText(frame, name, (left, y), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,
            0.75, (0, 255, 0), 2)

    if writer is None and args["output"] is not None:
        fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*"MJPG")
        writer = cv2.VideoWriter(args["output"], fourcc, 20,
            (frame.shape[1], frame.shape[0]), True)

    if writer is not None:
        writer.write(frame)

    if args["display"] > 0:
        cv2.imshow("Frame", frame)
        key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF

        if key == ord("q"):
            break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
vs.stop()

if writer is not None:
    writer.release()
```

I am able to detect and recognize faces using usb cam with this code but Now

I want detect using IP Cam instead of USB Cam.
My CP PLUS IP CAM is running on 192.168.1.181 and I want to use that cam to detect and recognize faces.

How can I use that IP CAM in this code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49978705/11666391).

Answer (score 2):

In your code just change one line,
**`vs = VideoStream(src="192.168.1.181/cam/realmonitorchannel=1&subtype=1&unicast=true&proto=Onvif").start()`**
let me know if it works.