# live streaming video on google cloud and real time computing

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, google-cloud-platform, face-recognition

I have developed an face recognition algorithm in python to work in real time, but it runs way too slow on my laptop. So I thought of deploying the algorithm on google cloud server and testing it. I am very new to google cloud and I need to know if I could stream my video feed from my webcam or IP camera directly to my algorithm on google cloud as in openCV. If yes please guide me through the steps.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In Google Cloud Platform you can create a [Compute Engine VM](https://cloud.google.com/compute) and install openCV on it. You can even [add GPUs](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gpus/add-gpus#create-new-gpu-instance) to your VM if required.

Regarding how to implement it, [here's](https://github.com/rena2damas/remote-opencv-streaming-live-video) a github repo that can give you some idea on how to stream the live video, and [here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49978705/access-ip-camera-in-python-opencv) a SO question regarding how to capture the video from the IP Camera.