# Access another system's webcam using opencv

Tags: python-3.x, opencv3.0

I am using openCV for facial detection using a web application. In order to get the videostream, I'll need to access the webcam of any random system connected to the same LAN network as mine (basically webcam of the user who visits that page).

I have tried using IPcam method

```
use = 'http://{}'.format(userip)
video = cv2.VideoCapture(use)
```

I tried with `http://` as well as `rtsp://` it results in

```
warning: Error opening file (/build/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:856)
warning: http://192.168.x.xxx (/build/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:857)
```

What am I missing/doing wrong?

Is there any method in opencv using which we can access the webcam of another machine which is on the same network as the machine I am using?

Any kind of help is appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Access IP Camera in Python OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49978705/access-ip-camera-in-python-opencv)

Comment: I am not accessing IP camera, I am accessing a webcam from another system