# Can I take a live stream URL and incorporate it into my code?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I'm trying to copy the URL of my phone that is live streaming, and import it into my code so that it opens a new window with the live stream visible.

The URL I'm trying to import is `https://192.168.1.69:8080`

Here's my code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

def make_coordinates(image, line_parameters):
    try:
        slope, intercept = line_parameters
    except TypeError:
        slope, intercept = 1,1
    y1 = image.shape[0]
    y2 = int(y1*(3/4)) #Line length
    x1 = int((y1 - intercept)/slope)
    x2 = int((y2 - intercept)/slope)
    return np.array([x1, y1, x2, y2])

def averaged_slope_intercept(image, lines):
    left_fit = []
    right_fit = []
    for line in lines:
        x1, y1, x2, y2 = line.reshape(4)
        parameters = np.polyfit((x1, x2), (y1, y2), 1)
        print(parameters)
        slope = parameters[0]
        intercept = parameters[1]
        if slope < 0:
            left_fit.append((slope, intercept))
        else:
            right_fit.append((slope, intercept))
    left_fit_average = np.average(left_fit, axis=0)
    right_fit_average = np.average(right_fit, axis=0)
    left_line = make_coordinates(image, left_fit_average)
    right_line = make_coordinates(image, right_fit_average)
    return np.array([left_line, right_line])

def canny(image):
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
    blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (5, 5), 0)
    canny = cv2.Canny(blur, 50, 150)
    return canny

def display_lines(image, lines):
    line_image = np.zeros_like(image)
    if lines is not None:
        for x1, y1, x2, y2 in lines:
            cv2.line(line_image, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (0, 255, 0), 2)
        return line_image

def region_of_interest(image):
    height = image.shape[0]
    polygons = np.array([
    [(300, height), (1300, height), (500, 400)] #Dimensions of Polygon
    ])
    mask = np.zeros_like(image)
    cv2.fillPoly(mask, polygons, 255)
    masked_image = cv2.bitwise_and(image, mask)
    return masked_image

# image = cv2.imread('test_image.jpg')
# lane_image = np.copy(image)
# canny_image = canny(lane_image)
# cropped_image = region_of_interest(canny_image)
# lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(cropped_image, 2, np.pi/180, 100, np.array([]), minLineLength=40, maxLineGap=5)
# averaged_lines = averaged_slope_intercept(lane_image, lines)
# line_image = display_lines(lane_image, averaged_lines)
# combo_image = cv2.addWeighted(lane_image, 0.8, line_image, 1, 1)
# cv2.imshow("result", combo_image)
# cv2.waitKey(0)

cap = cv2.VideoCapture("coast.mp4")
while(cap.isOpened()):
    _, frame = cap.read()
    canny_image = canny(frame)
    cropped_image = region_of_interest(canny_image)
    lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(cropped_image, 2, np.pi/180, 250, np.array([]), minLineLength=40, maxLineGap=5) #Number of minimum line votes
    averaged_lines = averaged_slope_intercept(frame, lines)
    line_image = display_lines(frame, averaged_lines)
    combo_image = cv2.addWeighted(frame, 0.8, line_image, 1, 1)
    cv2.imshow("Lane-Detection", combo_image)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('w'):
        break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I'm trying to place it where the "coast.mp4" is.

The code is for detecting lanes lines when driving, and I'm able to run the code with videos that are already downloaded on my computer (e.g. a video called "coast.mp4"), but I thought it would be interesting to see if I could implement a live stream so that the computer can detect lines in real-time. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

If this is a streaming URL, you can simply do it like this

```
cv2.VideoCapture("https://192.168.1.69:8080/video")
```

Comment: I have tried that, and the code runs successfully, but there is no window that pops up to allow me to view it, and it finishes in ~2 seconds.

Comment: @cheeseexpert , you need to make sure ur url is a streaming url. you can also try this 
cv2.VideoCapture("https://192.168.1.69:8080/video") you can also refer to this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49978705/access-ip-camera-in-python-opencv