# Access Xiaomi IP Camera in Python with OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, xiaomi

I'm trying to access my IP camera stream in Python.

Camera:
Xiaomi Mi Home Security Camera 360° 1080p

I got the IP address of the camera from the Mi Home app:
192.168.2.94

```
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('http://192.168.2.94')

while True:
    r, f = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow('IP Camera stream',f)
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#60>", line 4, in <module>
    cv2.imshow('IP Camera stream',f)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.5) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:182: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor'
```

Can you please help?

Comment: This is probably because your security camera isn't sharing the stream. see this point https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49978705/access-ip-camera-in-python-opencv

Comment: Thanks, there was a list of URLs there, and for Xiaomi they recommended: http://admin:admin@192.168.2.94:80/videofeed. I tried this, but got the same error. Not sure what should I use for the username:password combo.

Comment: I tried it on my xiaomi camera and also wasn't able to get it working, unfortunately.

Comment: Well thanks anyways for checking. I did some more research and found this article:
http://bobbyromeo.com/home-automation/xiaomi-smart-1080p-wifi-ip-camera-rtsp-streaming-hack
Turns out this Xiaomi camera disables RTSP by default. There is a hack on github mentioned in this article, but it was last updated in 2017 so I don't think that will work with new firmware versions.

Comment: @AdamSzabo-Toke has there been any progress on this? I'm in a similar situation now unfortunately, wondering if anyone has figured it out.

Comment: @MarcoFernandes It turns out Xiaomi is deliberately blocking the access to the stream. I did not find any working solution. Instead I bought a TP-LINK Tapo C310 which I am able to access through rtsp://login:password@IP/stream1 You can check the IP address of the camera in the Tapo app, and you can create a login/pass in the app as well. I was only able to access static frames, the above infinite loop made my IDLE crash.

Comment: I see, It's kind of suspicious that they would do that. I think I'll return mine under "false advertising" since it was advertised as an "IP camera" but actually has none of the functionality of an IP camera... Thank you for this information, appreciate it :)

Answer (score 1):

[here](https://answers.opencv.org/question/230143/opencv-connect-and-process-an-ip-camera-stream-rtsp-protocol/)

```
import cv2
# rtsp://username:password@192.168.2.94/port
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('rtsp://username:password@192.168.2.94/554')
while True:
    ret, img = cap.read()
    if ret == True:
        cv2.imshow('video output', img)
        k = cv2.waitKey(10)& 0xff
        if k == 27:
            break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm getting the same error with this as well. (I modified the IP address to mine)

Comment: check if you are allowed to use the cam, maybe you should give it a password @AdamSzabo-Toke

Comment: Thanks, I tried adding a password in Mi Home, but no success yet. Not sure what the username should be. I tried admin, root, and my profile ID in Mi Home.

Answer (score 1):

One year after question - but maybe still someone accessing this post :)

Xiaomi Camera's connects only to the cloud. There is no opened TCP/UDP ports that can be used for streaming directly to the endpoint device, or configure device via WebUI. That is irritating but security-friendly.

Only way to bypass this - is to flash custom OS for the camera.

Comment: please let me know if you flashed it