# OpenCV will not display IP camera feed, despite it showing up in browser

Tags: python, opencv, video-streaming, webcam

I'm trying to see my webcam feed using the open cv library. I am able to see my webcam feed when I go to https://192.168.1.214:80 on my browser, but when I try to look at it with Open CV I just get this:

`error: (-215:Assertion failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function 'imshow'`

I know this essentially means there's no image to show, but I dont understand why?

here is my code:

```
import cv2

WEBCAM_IP = 'http://192.168.1.214:80'

video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(WEBCAM_IP)

while True:
    ok, frame = video_capture.read()
    cv2.imshow('Video', frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
```

I have tried connecting a separate camera and just referring to the file in the VideoCapture() arguments, I've tried writing the IP in different ways, I'm completely at a loss.

Comment: might be a duplicate from this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45540069/access-ip-camera-with-opencv

Comment: Can you add ```/video``` at the end of your ip address?

Comment: @YunusTemurlenk `/video` does not work

Comment: @Xbattlax that thread solved my issue thanks, I guess I wasn't searching in the right place